# How to adjust div height according to facebook comments dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I have a html page that contains facebook comment plugin. When i add some comments, i want the height of container div grow dynamically.I think i should accomplish it by 2 steps:
step1-capture the add comment action.
step2-reset the div height.
I was stuck at step1, since the page won't refresh when someone add a comment.(PS:i do want to use scroll bar). Could someone tell me how to do it?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="facebook">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="example.com" data-num-posts="2"data-width="500"</div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase the height of comment box dynamically, the best way is to not specify height for container OR set the container height to auto

```
.container{
     height:auto !important;
}
```

Else, if you want to increase the height whenever a new comment is added, you can set the height on a callback function which is evoked whenever a comment is placed.

For more details in this check below link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: fbApplicationID,
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse XFBML  
            oauth: true,
            channelUrl: siteUrl + '/public/api/facebook/xd_receiver.htm'
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (res) { 
            //Your Code Here
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: // In your onload method
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', comment_callback);where should i put onload method?

Comment: i figure got it and thank you very much.Here is another problem How could i capture the "view more comments" event? because that action will extend the comment length too.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no event handler for the "view more" action

Comment: that is bad news, is there other ways to extend the page lenght? css way seems not working because the html is already created